# Group data into classes with numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame `df` from which I extract a column `mpg`.

I want to add class label/names to each row based on the value of `mpg`.

I have done it with

```
mpg = df.iloc[:,0]

median = np.percentile(mpg, q=50)
upper_quartile = np.percentile(mpg, q=75)
lower_quartile = np.percentile(mpg, q=25)

mpg_class = np.ones((num_observations, 1))

for i, element in enumerate(X):
    mpg = element[0]
    if mpg >= upper_quartile:
        mpg_class[i] = 3
    elif mpg >= median:
        mpg_class[i] = 2
    elif mpg >= lower_quartile:
        mpg_class[i] = 1
    else:
        mpg_class[i] = 0
```

but I wonder if it's possible to do way smarter with `numpy`? I guess it might be possible to do it with `np.where` or something like this.

Comment: Could you add a sample case? What is `X`?

Comment: `X` is a pandas dataframe with many variables, but I am only concerned about the vector `mpg = df.iloc[:,0]` which is just the first column, which contains float values between `10.0` and `90.0`.

Comment: Are you looking for [Pandas' Cut()?](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for [pd.qcut](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html):

```
pd.qcut(df.iloc[:, 0], [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3])
Out: 
0      1
1      0
2      1
3      0
4      0
5      0
6      0
...
```

The first parameter is the series you want to discretize. The second is the quantiles/percentiles. The last one is the labels (from 0 to 25% - 0, 25% to 50% - 1, etc.)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks!